# Input button unresponsive on Android Devices

Tags: android, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

Doing a sample webforms project w/ Bootstrap - I have a small form that asks for a user to select two items and an asp:Button for the user to submit their info:

```
   <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-horizontal">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Enter Your Details</legend>
            <div class="input-group" >
                <label for="lstItem1">Item 1 : </label>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="lstItem1" runat="server" CssClass="form-control "></asp:DropDownList>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group" >
                <label for="lstItem2">Item 2 : </label>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="lstItem2" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:DropDownList>
            </div>
            <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Let's Go!" CssClass="btn btn-success shadow-text" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />        
        </fieldset>
    </div>
```

That piece of code is contained in a bootstrap container class.

Everything works fine, except when I test it on a mobile device (Samsung Galaxy Note II Android 4.4 & Chrome 44, and an LG G3 w/ Chrome 44 as well), the button is completely unresponsive.  It's not that my event is not firing, the button has no response to it whatsoever!  It's baffling.

Here is all the extra CSS I've added that pertains to this block of code:

```css
.shadow-text{ text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black;}
.btn-success{display: block; z-index:999;}
.input-group { margin-bottom: 15px;}

legend
{
 position: relative;
 
 font-size: 1.5em;
 font-weight: bold;
    padding: 6px 20px 6px 70px;
    top: -30px;
 margin: 0px 10px 10px -30px;
 color: #EEE;
 background-color: #d09d90;
 text-shadow: 0px 1px 2px #bbb;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px #888;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px #888;
 box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px #888;
}
legend:after
{
 content: ' ';
 position: absolute;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 left: 0px;
 top: 100%;
 border-width: 5px 10px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: #666 #666 transparent transparent;
}

.form-horizontal{
    margin-top: 20px;
    border: 2px solid gray;
    padding: 10px;
    
}

.jumbotron, .form-horizontal{ background-color: #feeeea; margin-bottom:20px; }
```

So far I've tried:

1. Moving the button outside of the block of code shown above, and moved it outside of the fieldset.
2. Setting the z-index on the .btn class to 999.
3. Took out any "special effects" css, including shadow-text and legend (which is a ribbon effect for the legend).
4. Removed bootstrap-related input-group and form-control classes

^^ I've tried so much more but I'm fried from troubleshooting this for 6 hours, I can't even remember all that I've tried.

The one thing that **did** work, which is not an option, is (accidentally) I closed the surrounding container and added the button after the closing  tag.  This is not an option, as it screws up the flow with the rest of the columns.

Has anyone had any experience with this, and does anyone know if it's at all related to Bootstrap itself?

Final note - the btnSubmit_Click function contains one line of code, and it's a Response.Redirect that passes the selected values.

Comment: I've also tried getting rid of the surrounding container entirely, considering the button DID work when I accidentally closed it early.

Comment: Have you tried it without it being an asp:button?

Comment: Yes, that is one of the things I've tried.  Sorry.  I'm having problems remembering everything I've tried as I've been working on this for many hours now.

Comment: @chieftwopencils - I actually also tried a simple anchor tag - also didn't work.

Comment: Any attached javascript?  Also, anchor tag also froze?  Try using an anchor without the bootstrap classes defined on it?

Comment: You mean to the button itself?  No...  then yes and yes.

Bootstrap.js and jQuery are loaded though.